# Background css não funciona

Tags: css, html5

Boa noite, gostaria de saber porque quando eu uso esse style css na minha classe "bg" no meu html ele funciona, mas quando utilizo a versão HTML5, o estilo do background some completamente, procurei muito, mas não achei uma solução. Segue código.

Código HTML5:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código HTML normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .button {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #607d8b;
            border: none;
            color: white;
        }

        .textview {
            width: 217px;
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: none;
            color: #607d8b;
        }

        .main {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);

        }

        .bg {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #e91e63, #3f51b5);
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <form name='form'>
            <input class="textview" name="textview">
        </form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="C" onclick="clean()"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="<" onclick="back()"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="/" onclick="insert('/')"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="x" onclick="insert('*')"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="7" onclick="insert(7)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="8" onclick="insert(8)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="9" onclick="insert(9)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="-" onclick="insert('-')"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="4" onclick="insert(4)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="5" onclick="insert(5)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="6" onclick="insert(6)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="+" onclick="insert('+')"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="2" onclick="insert(2)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="3" onclick="insert(3)"> </td>
                <td rowspan="5"> <input class="button" style="height: 106px" type="button" value="=" onclick="equal()">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"> <input class="button" style="width: 106px;" type="button" value="0"
                        onclick="insert(0)"> </td>
                <td> <input class="button" type="button" value="." onclick="insert('.')"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta o código CSS cross browser, [crie o código CSS aqui](https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator):

```css
.bg{

    background: rgba(233,30,98,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(233,30,98,1) 0%, rgba(63,81,181,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(233,30,98,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(63,81,181,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(233,30,98,1) 0%, rgba(63,81,181,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(233,30,98,1) 0%, rgba(63,81,181,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(233,30,98,1) 0%, rgba(63,81,181,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(233,30,98,1) 0%, rgba(63,81,181,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e91e62', endColorstr='#3f51b5', GradientType=1 );

}

.medidas {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg medidas'></div>
```